# Authenticity of narration

Tags: hadith, authenticity

In [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57267/a-mat-is-better-than-a-barren-woman?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C295.9239), it is said that the narration is shaadh but I found another narration which aligns with it and it is alleged that it is authentic. I need to confirm the authenticity of it and wouldn't this mean that the narration cited in the other narration is not shaadh?

[Musnad Al-Faruq 499:](https://archive.org/stream/FP110402/02_110402#page/n131/mode/1up)

> It was narrated from Umar that he married a woman, had intercourse
> with her, and found that her black hair was streaked with white hair.
> He divorced her and said, “**A mat in a house is better than a woman who**
> **cannot bear children**, by Allah, that which is your most ardent wish.
> Nonetheless, I heard the Messenger of Allah ﷺ say, ‘Marry one who is
> loving and fertile, for I will boast of your great numbers before the
> nations on the Day of Resurrection.’”

The narration was graded as [Sahih](https://archive.org/stream/waq105201/06_105206#page/n65/mode/1up) by Al Arnaut.

Comment: The hadith quoted in your post and the one linked in Musnad al-Faruq already are different as it doesn't say"... is better than...". What al-Arnaut qualified as Sahih is the same hadith on which basis the one from Sunan Abi Dawod was declared as shadh as it has additions and meanings which are more than doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

**What al-Arnaut qualified as Sahih**

Sho'aib al-Arnaut declared the hadith as Sahih in the isnad, as none would regard any of:
Al-Qa'naby->Malik->ibn Shihab->Salim adn Hamzah sons of -> ibn 'Umar

as untrustworthy narrators. All of them are rather of a high level of trust. However none of them reported the statement of 'umar they rather reported the hadith saying:

> "An omen is in a dwelling, a woman or a horse." ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/30/19))

Even al-Bukhari and Muslim quoted the

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Evil omen is in the women, the house and the horse.'
> (Sahih al-Bukhari [here via ibn Shihab](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2858) and [here via Malik](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5093) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2225a))

In 'Umdat al-Qary al-'Ayni  said that this hadith is matruk from the apparent meaning as else this would mean the prophet() is contradicting himself when declaring omen as shirk. Which means the hadith assuming its authenticity and attribution is correct must not be understood in literal l why rather on the condition of the more correct narration.

Further al-Arnaut explained that this hadith was narrated with the wording:

> "If there is evil omen in anything, it is in the house, the woman and the horse."

Which emphasizes a condition and which is regarded more sane (Sahih) as it appears in both Sahih's of al-Bukhari and Muslim (both have been addressed in my reworked answer on the post you are referring to) and many other ahadith imply it too see for example in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3921) and [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1993).

**The quote from Musnad al-Farooq**

Interestingly ibn Kathir here quoted a narrator chain for a statement of 'Umar that other scholars pretended not too find any. This requires a bit more investigation.

Sho'aib al-Arnaut commented both additions to this hadith from Sunan abi DAwod saying that the narrative of the statement (athar) attributed to imam Malik is Sahih at least the narrators are trustworthy. Please note that he missed to point at the gap between abu Dawod and Malik!
As for the statement (athar) attributed to 'Umar() he said it is quoted in a book of ibn abi ad-Dunya and sahih in Tarikh Baghdad of al-Khateeb al-Baghdadi, however the statement seems to say it is regarded as sahih by al-Khateeb al-Baghdadi (investigation is needed).